# System.UriTemplate.BindByName and WebApi Array Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, url-template

I am using UriTemplate (System.ServiceModel) to bind a template to an object and create a url

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://example.com");
var template = new UriTemplate("");

var properties = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"a", "2"},
    {"a", "3"}
};

Assert.Equal(
    new Uri(baseUri, "?a=1&a=2&a=3"),
    template.BindByName(baseUri, properties));
```

=>

```
Expected: http://example.com/?a=1&a=2&a=3

Actual:   http://example.com/?a=1%2c2%2c3
```

The expected result will work for a webapi endpoint, but the actual does not as the convention of comma separating a parameter is not official and not supported by web api

Is there a way I can get the expected result?

I do need to use url templating for binding values (e.g. `{one}/two/{three}`), though not necessarily UriTemplate from System.ServiceModel - what does WebApi use? is it exposed?

Comment: I don't think that you can achieve this behaviour using the standard .NET classes. Probably, all of them will merge the values into an array.

Comment: from what I've seen your probably right, seems the servicemodel framework is not compatible with the webapi - but it may be someone has solved this before so will leave this open